# Micro-services with load balancing and commits

Tags: transactions, commit, microservices, serverless-architecture

I am keen on understanding the following aspects of micro-services.

- **Commit and roll-back**. If a business goal is to be achieved by invoking multiple micro-services, who co-ordinates commit and roll-back? Are micro-services required to embed the commit-roll-back protocol in their implementation? Or, is it provided by some external factor?
- **Load-balancing for micro-services**. Is a micro-service front-ended by a load balancer to help it scale? And, therefore, scaling is out of scope of implementation of the service?
- **Co-relation with AWS Lambda/Bluemix OpenWhisk/Azure Functions**. How do micro-services compare with ‘serverless’ architecture?

Comment: You question (questions, really) are very broad and do not fit into the SO model. I suggest you do some research and come back with actual, concrete problems.  what you're looking for are white papers, not SO answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the transactions should be handled at microservice level but at some point a rollback mechanism or 2-phase commit may be necessary for transactions spanning across various services.